# Are there instances of batsmen walking despite a lack of appeal from the fielding side?

Tags: cricket, trivia

This is a follow-up question to [this earlier question on instances where the fielding team did not appeal for a wicket.](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15177/)

Are there any recorded instances where the batsman chose to walk, after realising that they have nicked the ball, without any appeal from the fielding side?

This would of course constitute exemplary sportsmanship, and the chances of such an instance would be extremely low in the modern era where the game has become increasingly competitive.

For the sake of this question, all international formats of the game, first class and upper levels of domestic cricket can be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instances that I could find, where the batsman chose to walk, after realising that they have nicked the ball, without any appeal from the fielding side (at least not until they choose to walk out) are [Kumar Sangakkara against England](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=l0DFbLCAAW0) (not sure which match) and [Hashim Amla for KXIP against RCB](http://www.iplt20.com/video/102521/hashim-amla-the-fair-play-ambassador-).

Answer (score 1):

The most famous (relatively) recent incident of this was in the Australia vs Sri Lanka semifinal of the 2003 World Cup, where [Adam Gilchrist walked, despite being given as not out by the umpire](http://www.icc-cricket.com/cricket-world-cup/greatest-100-moments/122/gilchrist-walks-in-03). That's potentially a slightly different situation in the modern day and age of DRS when the Sri Lankans would have had the option to review the decision, but still definitely stands as an example of good sportsmanship.

Comment: Truly a remarkable moment of sportsmanship, but the fielding side was clearly appealing the wicket before Gilchrist walked. I am looking for instances where a batsman walked even though there was no appeal from the fielding side.

Comment: ".. despite a lack of appeal", ".. regardless of/without any appeal".

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what you mean by walking, really. I mean, these days it's uncommon for the fielding team not to appeal immediately at any whiff of a chance, however faint.

Don't think I've ever seen a batsman walk without the fielding team at least thinking there might be a chance, and appealing. Seen them walk when the umpire gave a not-out, sure - Gilchrist's famous example was noted in another reply.

However, it's not uncommon for batsmen to retire (hurt, for example). If that counts as walking without appeal, I guess technically I'd go with "yes" :)

Note that a batsman cannot be given out without appeal (law changes re misbehavior notwithstanding), but an appeal is not required for a batsman to walk.